# excel fix column value, vary row value, non contiguous row

Tags: excel

I have a list of 5 columns (A-E) and multiple rows (2-89), and need to derive select rows (e.g. 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 14, 21) from the list with only two of the columns I am interested in (e.g. col A and C).

I have picked out all the values of column A (since my data set is irregular, and i can't figure out a way to automate this), is there a way to copy just the row value, but change the column value to "C" in the other cell?

I have:

```
A1
A4
A6
A8
A10
A11
A14
A21
```

So I want effectively:

```
A1 C1
A4 C4
A6 C6
A8 C8
A10 C10
A11 C10
A14 C14
A21 C21
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this question is really trivial! I can't seem to find the right answers googling.

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,'A','C')

Comment: Have a look at the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"A";"C")
```